# SQL narrowing down the results of a query with lag and lead

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am writing a query using lag and lead to look back and get a person's previous activity, current activity and next activity.  Unfortunately, the results do not come out correctly as explained later.  I need it to display the currentvalue, new_activity_code that preceded it(previous value) as well as which activity code will occur next(nextvalue).

I need it to only show the the current activity and the previously mentioned items.  I need it to work for multiple debtors but not multiple entries of the same debtor.

example table:

Table invoice_activity:

```
Invoice_id    debtorId      New_activity_Code           Next_activity_date
  456         00001            123456                           1/2/2015
  741         00002            123456                           2/2/2015
  147         00002            789123                           2/16/2015
  258         00003            987321                           2/24/2015
  369         00004            852369                           2/23/2015
  753         00002            753357                           3/16/2015
  951         00003            428619                           3/24/2015
  428         00004            951628                           3/23/2015
  852         00003            123456                           3/24/2015
  963         00004            123456                           4/11/2015
  654         00001            456789                           5/8/2015
```

The example output:

```
Debtor ID       PreviousValue     CurrentValue      NextValue     Next_act_date
00001               123456           456789           NULL           5/8/2015
00002               123456           789123           753357         3/16/2015
00003               123456           987321           428619         3/24/2015
00004               123456           852369           951628         3/23/2015
```

What I seem to be getting is what appears to be the output but it repeats for every new invoice.

Query:

```
SELECT
    distinct
    debtor_id,
    LAG(ia.new_activity_code) OVER (partition by debtor_id ORDER BY debtor_id) PreviousValue, 
    ia.new_activity_code,
    max(next_activity_date) as next_act_date
FROM
    invoice_activity ia 
WHERE
    debtor_id IN
        (SELECT
             distinct debtor_id
         FROM
             debtor
         WHERE
             client_id=1234)
GROUP BY
    debtor_id,
    new_activity_code
ORDER BY
    next_act_date
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the new analytic functions in SQL 2012 but maybe you should look into the `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` functions instead of `LAG`

Comment: unfortunately, the example table is probably a million entries shorter and there are IDs that are the same throughout the database which means the first value would be the first ever and the last value, the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you actually expect as the result, is it the one for each debtor where the one happening next (e.g. the one smallest but in the future)? I think this returns that:

```
select
  debtor_id, 
  previous_value,
  new_activity_code,
  Next_Value,
  next_activity_date
from (
  select
    debtor_id,
    previous_value,
    new_activity_code,
    Next_Value,
    next_activity_date,
    row_number() over (partition by debtor_id 
        order by next_activity_date asc) as rn
  from(
    SELECT
        debtor_id,
        LEAD(ia.new_activity_code) OVER (partition by debtor_id 
            ORDER BY Next_activity_date desc) Previous_Value, 
        LAG(ia.new_activity_code) OVER (partition by debtor_id 
            ORDER BY Next_activity_date desc) Next_Value, 
        ia.new_activity_code,
        Next_activity_date
    FROM
        invoice_activity ia 
  ) t
  where
    next_activity_date > getdate()
 ) t
where rn = 1
```

One problem is that there is a duplicate record in the data, or at least I wasn't sure how this should be handled since it's the same debtor and same date:

```
951         00003            428619                           3/24/2015
852         00003            123456                           3/24/2015
```

And at least if my analysis was correct, for debtor 2 this should have been he correct answer:

```
753         00002            753357                           3/16/2015
```

Instead of this (which is found as the previous value):

```
147         00002            789123                           2/16/2015
```

And for the SQL, the innermost select gets each of the row + the next value for it (by date descending), then the one outside it assigns the rows a row number in reverse order (date ascending) to get the one closest to current day + filters out rows that are in the past and the outermost select gets just the ones with rn = 1.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, it seems that I had written my question poorly.  in the end though, i need the previousvalue and nextvalue to show what preceded the current action and what will occur after the current action.

Comment: Not sure if I even still understand the problem. Added one column for the next action, assuming current action is the one which has the date in the future, but still your example result doesn't really match that.

Comment: I apologize for the somewhat confusing question.  I found your answer to be most helpful in solving the problem.  The only modification made was removing the date range line.  i was using dates in order to place the data gathered from the lags and leads in a specific order.